# Inserting into dynamic table partition in postgresql with return

Tags: postgresql

I created a table partition that will create a table if it is not yet existing the table names are on a monthly basis.  I need this function to return the inserted ID but I'm getting this error of column "partition" does not exist it seems that my schema(partition) is considered column in this code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partition.itinerary_partition_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
    reflowId bigint;
    _tablename text;
    _startyear text;
    _startmonth text;
    _fulltablename text;
BEGIN
    --Takes the current inbound "time" value and determines when midnight is for the given date
    _startyear := to_char(now(), 'YYYY');
    _startmonth := to_char(now(), 'MM');
    _tablename := 'itinerary_'||_startyear || '_' || _startmonth;
    _fulltablename := 'partition.' || _tablename;

    -- Check if the partition needed for the current record exists
    PERFORM 1
    FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
    JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    WHERE  c.relkind = 'r'
    AND    c.relname = _tablename
    AND    n.nspname = 'partition';

    -- If the partition needed does not yet exist, then we create it:
    -- Note that || is string concatenation (joining two strings to make one)
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE partition.' || quote_ident(_tablename) || '()INHERITS (partition.itinerary)';

        -- Table permissions are not inherited from the parent.
        -- If permissions change on the master be sure to change them on the child also.
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE partition.' || quote_ident(_tablename) || ' OWNER TO postgres';

        -- Indexes are defined per child, so we assign a default index that uses the partition columns
        EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX ' || quote_ident(_tablename||'_indx1') || ' ON partition.' || quote_ident(_tablename) || ' (id)';
    END IF;

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I SELECT $1.*', "partition." || _tablename)
        USING NEW;
        RETURN NEW; 
    END;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

After this code I am calling it in another insert function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION partition.insert_data(username text,jsonData jsonb) RETURNS bigint AS
$$
DECLARE reflowId bigint;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO reflow_partition.itinerary(username, data)
    VALUES (username, jsonData) RETURNING id;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I SELECT $1.*', "partition." || _tablename)
```

to this:

```
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %1$I.%2$I SELECT $1.*', 'partition', _tablename)
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply.  It did change the error I'm getting.  I am now getting Error: pq: relation "partition.itinerary_2017_05" does not exist.  I'm really sorry got stuck with this for days now.

Comment: I have updated my answer and tested locally - now it works. It was creating invalid identificator: `"partition.itinerary_2017_05"`, now it will do correct one: `"partition"."itinerary_2017_05"`